# What does KRT mean in this diagram?

Tags: audio, notation

I am working on building a reverb. [This article](http://www.spinsemi.com/knowledge_base/effects.html#Reverberation) explains how to build a reverb pretty well, but I do not understand what the KRT in the main diagram stands for. The article says `The term Krt controls reverb time`, but what does the actual block do?

[image]

Comment: I guess it's just a multiplier.

Comment: After implementing the rest of this, I guess it's pretty clear that you are correct.